# How to add event listener to an element when it created with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to create and add event listener to a button in jquery. I'm able to achieve this, but What is my problem is that when I click any of the button in the form, this event is triggering.

here is my code:

```
$('#submitPh').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
secCheck($(this).attr('id'));
});

function  secCheck(invoker) {
    console.log('called');
    var id = 'secModal', title = '<h3>Security Verification</h3>',
    body = $('<form/>').attr({'method': 'post', 'action': '', 'id': 'secCheck'}).append($('<div/>').addClass('form-group')
         .append($('<div/>').addClass('controls')
         .append($('<label/>').attr({'for': 'verPass'}).addClass('control-label').text('Please enter your password'), $('<input/>').attr({'type': 'password', 'id': 'verPass', 'name': 'verPass', 'value': '', 'placeholder': 'Enter your password'})
         .addClass('form-control'))), $('<div/>').addClass('form-group').append($('<div/>').addClass('col-lg-10 warning-mes')),$('<div/>').addClass('form-group').append($('<button/>').click(confCheck()).attr({'type': 'button', 'id': 'secCheckSubmit'}).addClass('btn btn-default').text('Submit')));
            createModal(id, title, body, invoker);       
}

function createModal(id, title, body, invoker) {
   var modal = $('<div/>').attr('id', id).addClass('modal fade')
       .append($('<div/>').addClass('modal-dialog')
       .append($('<div/>').addClass('modal-content')
       .append($('<div/>').addClass('modal-header')
       .append($('<button/>').attr({'data-dismiss': 'modal', 'area-hidden': true}).addClass('close').html('&times'), title), $('<div/>').addClass('modal-body').html(body), $('<div/>').addClass('modal-footer')
.append($('<button/>').attr({'type': 'button', 'data-dismiss': 'modal'}).addClass('btn btn-default').text('Close')))));
            if (!$('div#' + id).length) {
                $('body').append(modal);
            }
            showModal('#' + id, invoker);
        }
function showModal(sId, invoker) {
    var $this = invoker;
    var id = sId;
    var $target = $(sId || (id && id.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))); //strip for ie7
            var option = $target.data('modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({remote: !/#/.test(id) && id}, $target.data());

            this.modal = $target
                    .modal(option, this)
                    .one('hide', function() {
                        $this.is(':visible') && $this.focus();
                    });
        }
function confCheck() {
            alert();
        }
```

This is how I did. But this was not producing the expected result as I stated above.

Please anyone help me to solve this problem...

**Edit**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKwvS/1/)

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle sample

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have created the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cKwvS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
$('<button/>').click(confCheck)
```

You need to pass a function reference as the parameter to `click()`, don't invloke it ans sent the result

Comment: @james `$('<button/>').click(function(){confCheck(yourparams)})`

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I have one more question not related to this. How can I pass function as argument with its arguments.

Comment: @james you can have a look at [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Sorry arun `bind()` is not working for me here how I'm calling the function `sp.secCheck($(this).attr('id'), sp.updateSecQuest,data);` if I use bind `secCheck` function also won't invoke.

Comment: @james how did you use bind

Comment: I used `sp.secCheck($(this).attr('id'), sp.updateSecQuest.bind(),data);` But I'm receiving it in another function and passing it to another and there I'm calling this function..

Comment: @james not sure what you are trying to do... can you share the definitions of these function

Comment: did you find any issue in my script

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) in this context

Try,

```
$('<button/>').appendTo('#button').click(sp.confCheck(func,data));
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny and his comment's upvoters: OP has registered the event before appending the element into the DOM, and my code will register the event after appending the element to the DOM.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy If I'm creating the #button also with jquery before creating the button then how can I achieve this...

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that does not matter because you are binding the handler to a element

Comment: @ArunPJohny and @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I want to know how to add this event  If I'm creating the `#button` also with jquery  before creating the button

Answer (score 0):

better you should give a class name for the newly created button and provide deligate for event listening

```
 $('#button').append($('<button/>', { class: "test" }));
        $("body").on("click", ".test", function () { });
```